# Replacing merge fields with our values in code

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word

I have this Text: `Hello <<FirstName>>  <<LastName>>` in which the <> and <> are merge fields in a document, and I have a list of customers in an array which I want to allocate them to these fields. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more info...

Comment: Do you want to create one docx per customer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you have your array structured, but:

```
        Dim text As String = "Hello <<FirstName>> <<LastName>>"
        Dim foo() As String 
        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(foo)
            Dim modifiedText As String = text
            modifiedText = Replace(modifiedText, "<<FirstName>>", foo(i,0), 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
            modifiedText = Replace(modifiedText, "<<LastName>>", foo(i,1), 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
            Console.WriteLine(modifiedText)

        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to [merge the field values in a Word document using VB.NET](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/mail-merge-and-reporting.html). If I'm correct, you may try [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx). This component provides a comprehensive solution for such merging scenarios.

Here is a simple code snippet as well:

```
' Open an existing document.

Dim doc As New Document(MyDir & "MailMerge.ExecuteArray.doc")



' Fill the fields in the document with user data.

doc.MailMerge.Execute(New String() {"FullName", "Company", "Address", "Address2", "City"}, New Object() {"James Bond", "MI5 Headquarters", "Milbank", "", "London"})



' Send the document in Word format to the client browser with an option to save to disk or open inside the current browser.

doc.Save(Response, "PersonalizedLetter Out.doc", ContentDisposition.Inline, Nothing)
```

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.